# DropDownList: call class method by changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, onchange, dropdownbox

my problem is the following:

- I create a class for a dropt-down list, with a methode to create the drop-down-list
- I want to call an other methode "select_entry_in_list" when the user select an other entry in the list

But that's not working in this way.

I try it at following way:[Link www.w3schools.com - editor](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FS2Q4C5WI2IA)

```
// track the change event - jquery
$('#xv_select_typ').on('change', function() {
      this.obj_opt.select_entry_in_list();
});​

// called by a Button (onclick)
function create(){
    this.obj_opt = new opt();
    this.obj_opt.create_option_list();
}​

// Option list class
class opt {    

    // create the option list
    create_option_list(){ 

        var list_entrys = [
            [1,"Hallo"],
            [3,"buongiorno"],
            [5,"bonjour"]
        ];

        var list = "<select id='xv_select_typ'>";
        var opt_entry;

        list = list + "<option>-</option>";

        for (var key in list_entrys) {  

          var entry_name = list_entrys[key][1];
          opt_entry = "<option entry_id='"+key+"'>"                 
            + entry_name   
            + "</option>";
          list = list + opt_entry;​
        }
        list = list + "</select>"; 

        $('#sec').html(list);
    }  

    // When an entry of the list will changed
    select_entry_in_list(){
        alert("WORK!");
    }

}
```

Comment: Your problem is that the select does not exist yet when you try to add the event to it. As mario shows, you need to add the event After the dropdown list ash been added to the page. Two sidenotes: 1) `this` is window in your script, in other words, you add obj_opt to the global namespace. If that's not what you want, use a variable instead. 2) Your class definition also does not contain a constructor.

Comment: Thank's for the explanation. 
The code is just the snippet from the hole Project, constructor exists there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the select event handler into the create function like this:

```
    // called by Button
function create(){
    self.obj_opt = new opt();
    self.obj_opt.create_option_list();
        // track the change event
$('#xv_select_typ').on('change', function() {
      self.obj_opt.select_entry_in_list();
});

}
```

Comment: You're welcome. But make sure, that you don't assign the event handler multiple times :) And please mark the question as solution if it helped you.